# Compiling a specific program in linux kernel/Documentation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am cross compiling linux kernel. I have the following program which compiles perfectly well when I run make from ti's directory

```
kernel/Documentation/virtual/lguest
```

however when I compile the linux kernel and then boot the kernel image on the target machine that lguest program is nowhere. (I confirmed it by running find / -name lguest)

How can I make sure that the lguest programs goes somewhere into the linux kernel ?

Comment: Probably, depending on your cross compilation toolchain, you can set configuration to add/remove binaries from the binary image you are also going to upload on your target. The lguest program is not really part of the kernel (I mean, you cannot link it with the kernel image)

Comment: As sergico said, how to include a userspace binary would depend on the sort of root filesystem image you are generating - no one can help you with that without more details of your system.  Another option you can try (for a quick test) is to transfer it onto the device by a means such as ftp, once it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have to cd Documentation/virtual/lguest and explicitly do a "make" in that directory:

cd Documentation/virtual/lguest

make

cc -m32 -Wall -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -O3 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE    lguest.c   -o lguest

Comment: The poster already said they could build the program by running make from its directory; the problem is with getting it installed in the system image (and the difference between that image and the kernel proper)

Comment: Maybe the Makefile there has an `install` target, though for this type of thing, I'm guessing the maintainer didn't bother. Just copy the binary manually to where-ever you want it installed.

Comment: yes that is true. I can make it but cant find it in the kernel image. As the comments to my question point out probably that will never happen. The relief is to know that I can manually copy paste the executable and it will still owkr.

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/virtualization@lists.linux-foundation.org/msg01601.html

and this 600+ pages slide:

http://www.jquigley.com/files/talks/lguest.pdf

not sure if it helped?